# How to preset the decimal separator for a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, locale, shinydashboard, decimal-point

I need to set the separator for decimals for my app, so it is independent from the browser language settings.

I'm using 'shinydashboard' package. The page includes numeric inputs that have the decimal separator changed to a comma, whenever the up/down arrow is clicked.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? E.g. set the number format in advance, so it stays fixed no matter what?

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    numericInput(
      inputId = "add_weight", 
      label = "Weight:", 
      value = 0.01, 
      min = 0, 
      max = 1, 
      step = 0.01
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Even if I set the value to, say, "0.01", as soon as I click on up arrow button the "0.01" becomes "0,02".

Comment: Could you solve your Problem? I am struggling with the same issue at the moment.